# Combining arrays from different MySQL entries and removing duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL database with varying rows and a specific column with arrays which I wish to combine and then remove the duplicates. For example, the following entries, `row1 ([0] => 1) row2 ([0] => 2 [1] => 3)` and `row3 ([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3)`. I need to combine them and remove duplicates like this:

```
rows ([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3)
```

I have called the query from the database as follows and since the entries are stored by comma separation, (1,2,3), I used the explode function to get them in the format above.

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND micro_analysis<>'';";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
            $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
            $micro_analysis = $input['micro_analysis'];
            $micro_analyses = explode(',', $micro_analysis); 
            print_r($result2);
```

From here I cannot seem to get the array from each separate row, it only gives a array result from the first row and thus affects my downstream results. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Put the mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2) on While loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it as comma separated string and then [explode](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) it and make it [unique](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp). You can then use [array_filter](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_filter.asp) to remove any null or empty values

Also, you have missed looping the result set to fetch all values returned from the query.

Here' is the updated snippet,

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND micro_analysis<>'';";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

$micro_analysis = '';
while($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $micro_analysis .= $input['micro_analysis'] . ',';
}

$micro_analysis_arr = array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $micro_analysis)));
```

Comment: Beautiful, works nicely! Why did you do this: $micro_analysis = '';

Comment: It's always a good practice to declare variables. If in future you add an outer loop, `$micro_analysis` will get appended for all results which won't be desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND micro_analysis<>'';";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

$micro_analysis = array();
while($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $micro_analysis[] = $input['micro_analysis'];
}

$micro_analysis_arr = array_unique($micro_analysis);
```

**Hope this will help you**